# Some crashes of Flutter framework not reported to crashlytics

Tags: flutter, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

We have an iOS native project, and we are opening some Flutter screens following the official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=no-engine-vc-uikit-swift-tab). After integration, we noticed that some users are experiencing crashes in the Flutter framework. These crashes are not being reported to Crashlytics, although we can see them in the Apple Feedback Crashes tool.

Attached is the stack trace of one of the crashes that we personally encountered and submitted to the Apple Feedback tool, but we didn't observe it in Firebase Crashlytics.

```
Incident Identifier: 3CE97C56-4B18-4ED3-BC6D-1CCE93618492
Hardware Model:      iPhone15,3
Process:             MyNativeApp [29650]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F2506398-CA6C-4466-AF8E-A58F87560C67/MyNativeApp.app/MyNativeApp
Identifier:          com.MyNativeApp.ios.MyNativeAppapp
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
AppStoreTools:       15C5500a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone15,3:17
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyNativeApp.ios.production.MyNativeAppapp [4331]

Date/Time:           2024-01-09 16:50:58.9132 +0300
Launch Time:         2024-01-09 16:47:45.9748 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.0.03
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  11


Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter







Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed738b7c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc84fd4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Flutter                         0x000000010800ef40 std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::condition_variable::wait(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_lock<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::mutex>&) + 20 (condition_variable.cpp:47)
3   Flutter                         0x000000010829f60c fml::AutoResetWaitableEvent::Wait() + 56 (waitable_event.cc:0)
4   Flutter                         0x00000001083c495c flutter::Shell::Screenshot(flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotType, bool) + 344 (shell.cc:2137)
5   Flutter                         0x0000000107fe34c8 -[FlutterView drawLayer:inContext:] + 100 (FlutterView.mm:151)
6   QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1768 -[CALayer _renderForegroundInContext:] + 1712 (CALayer.mm:9633)
7   QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2ae8 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1200 (CALayer.mm:9153)
8   QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
18  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
19  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
20  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
21  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
22  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab1050 -[CALayer _renderSublayersInContext:] + 332 (CALayer.mm:9677)
23  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a7ab2af4 -[CALayer renderInContext:] + 1212 (CALayer.mm:9154)
24  MyNativeApp                     0x00000001013c5bd0 -[UXViewVideoHandler renderLayer:inContent:] + 52
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae1e9300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae1f878c _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 92 (queue.c:1570)
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae1e9300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae1f7998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984 (queue.c:7813)
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ae1f75b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7973)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a626320c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625ff18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996 (CFRunLoop.c:3149)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625f668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
33  GraphicsServices                0x00000001e962a5ec GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a867c2b4 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3685)
35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a867b8f0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5270)
36  MyNativeApp                     0x0000000100502da4 main + 176 (main.swift:11)
37  dyld                            0x00000001c8cb2dcc start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc859fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed7381d8 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed737f70 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed737e88 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed737cc8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a6261d0c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625fc04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625f668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001a51f854c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a522627c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a85ddfc8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420 (UIEventFetcher.m:1208)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a527d184 __NSThread__start__ + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc864d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc85a10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)



Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed74101c __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc89680 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1681)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ae2a1b90 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   Flutter                         0x000000010829c688 fml::LogMessage::~LogMessage() + 0 (logging.cc:100)
4   Flutter                         0x000000010829c854 fml::FileMapping::CreateReadOnly(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::basic_string<char, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::char_traits<char>, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::allocator<char>> const&) + 0 (mapping.cc:21)
5   Flutter                         0x000000010830e878 flutter::DlSkCanvasDispatcher::drawTextFrame(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::shared_ptr<impeller::TextFrame> const&, float, float) + 56 (dl_sk_dispatcher.cc:278)
6   Flutter                         0x00000001082f8c88 flutter::DisplayList::Dispatch(flutter::DlOpReceiver&, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, flutter::Culler&) const + 3068 (display_list.cc:197)
7   Flutter                         0x000000010830b1c0 flutter::DlSkCanvasAdapter::DrawDisplayList(sk_sp<flutter::DisplayList>, float) + 324 (dl_sk_canvas.cc:0)
8   Flutter                         0x000000010845e928 flutter::DisplayListLayer::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 2128 (display_list_layer.cc:160)
9   Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
10  Flutter                         0x000000010845b884 flutter::ClipShapeLayer<SkRect>::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 756 (clip_shape_layer.h:100)
11  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
12  Flutter                         0x0000000108467180 flutter::TransformLayer::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 84 (transform_layer.cc:75)
13  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
14  Flutter                         0x0000000108467180 flutter::TransformLayer::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 84 (transform_layer.cc:75)
15  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
16  Flutter                         0x0000000108467180 flutter::TransformLayer::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 84 (transform_layer.cc:75)
17  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
18  Flutter                         0x000000010845b884 flutter::ClipShapeLayer<SkRect>::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 756 (clip_shape_layer.h:100)
19  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
20  Flutter                         0x0000000108467180 flutter::TransformLayer::Paint(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 84 (transform_layer.cc:75)
21  Flutter                         0x000000010845d138 flutter::ContainerLayer::PaintChildren(flutter::PaintContext&) const + 88 (container_layer.cc:0)
22  Flutter                         0x0000000108463ef0 flutter::LayerTree::Paint(flutter::CompositorContext::ScopedFrame&, bool) const + 1308 (layer_tree.cc:0)
23  Flutter                         0x000000010845860c flutter::CompositorContext::ScopedFrame::Raster(flutter::LayerTree&, bool, flutter::FrameDamage*) + 3684 (compositor_context.cc:154)
24  Flutter                         0x00000001083a6ec0 flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotLayerTreeAsImage(flutter::LayerTree*, flutter::CompositorContext&, GrDirectContext*, bool) + 276 (rasterizer.cc:755)
25  Flutter                         0x00000001083a5800 flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotLastLayerTree(flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotType, bool) + 868 (rasterizer.cc:0)
26  Flutter                         0x00000001083c4ba0 std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__function::__func<flutter::Shell::Screenshot(flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotType, bool)::$_0, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::allocator<flutter::Shell::Screenshot(flutter::Rasterizer::ScreenshotType, bool)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 64 (function.h:359)
27  Flutter                         0x000000010829db9c fml::MessageLoopImpl::FlushTasks(fml::FlushType) + 568 (message_loop_impl.cc:128)
28  Flutter                         0x00000001082a1330 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::OnTimerFire(__CFRunLoopTimer*, fml::MessageLoopDarwin*) + 32 (message_loop_darwin.mm:86)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a62d95d0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1797)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a62d9278 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1004 (CFRunLoop.c:2404)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a6262e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 288 (CFRunLoop.c:2562)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625fe8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1856 (CFRunLoop.c:3122)
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a625f668 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
34  Flutter                         0x00000001082a141c fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88 (message_loop_darwin.mm:52)
35  Flutter                         0x00000001082a0a90 void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct>>, fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>>(void*) + 208 (thread:295)
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc864d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020fc85a10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)



Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on macOS 14.2 23C64 darwin-arm64, locale en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Ali’s iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
QTYPFWXD6G:FlutterDesktop a.ali15$ flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7f20e5d18c (7 weeks ago) • 2023-11-27 09:47:30 -0800
Engine • revision 22b600f240
Tools • Dart 3.2.1 • DevTools 2.28.3
QTYPFWXD6G:FlutterDesktop a.ali15$
```